# Websockets and Vagrant

Tags: php, websocket, vagrant, ratchet

I am using websockets in PHP with this [Ratchet](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet) library. It is working great in my local machine(without vagrant).

### Server-side code:

```
$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$realtimeApp = new Ratchet\App('localhost', 2282, '0.0.0.0', $loop);
$loop->run();
```

### Client-side code:

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:2282');
conn.onopen = function (e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};
conn.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log("Connection error!");
};
conn.onclose = function (e) {
    console.log("Connection closed!");
    console.log(e);
};
```

But, when I use it in my virtual machine(with vagrant), it does not work.

### Server-side code:

```
$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$realtimeApp = new Ratchet\App('192.168.56.101', 2282, '0.0.0.0', $loop);
$loop->run();
```

### Client-side code:

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.56.101:2282');
conn.onopen = function (e) {
   console.log("Connection established!");
};
conn.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log("Connection error!");
};
conn.onclose = function (e) {
    console.log("Connection closed!");
    console.log(e);
};
```

Comment: you get connection error ?

Comment: Yes, I get a connection error.

Comment: Can you post the HTTP error you get in your browser? If you're in Chrome you'll find this under the Network tab in the Developer Tools.

Comment: This issue is fixed. I had also created issue in ratchet. See [this](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/209).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [puphpet](http://puphpet.com) to generate puppet manifests. The problem was caused by a firewall. By default, puphpet blocks all the ports except 22(for SSH) and 80(for apache and ngnix). I created firewall rule from the puphpet GUI and run `vagrant provision` and it worked.